# jQuery highlighting not working on a bootstrap v4 button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am trying to highlight the text of a button when another button is clicked.

An oversimplified version of my html would look like this :

```js
$(".abth").click(function(e) {
  var btnid = '#'.concat($(this).text());
  var divPosition = $(btnid).offset();
  console.log(btnid);
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: divPosition.top}, "slow"); //this is working
  $(btnid).effect("highlight", {color: "#FFFFFF"}, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<li class="page-item abth"><a class="page-link" href="#">A</a></li>
<button type="button" id="A" class="btn btn-secondary alphabutton">A</button>
```

The problem is that the jquery highlighting will work on a regular button, but in this case it will not work as my button is a bootstrap button. Any clues how to make the highlighting work on a bootstrap button?

P.S. My bootstrap version is 4.0. Apparently my code will work with earlier versions of Bootstrap.

Comment: what part isn't working? its working here https://jsfiddle.net/andrewgi/7pzf8u8g/

Comment: What exactly "isn't working" I pasted your code into a fiddle and it does exactly what I think it should.

Comment: @andrewgi hmm, I can view it in a fiddle, when I tried to create a snippet I had to also link the css file.

Comment: @andrewgi The highlighting functionality isn't working as I have stated in my question. And still isn't. I had a look at your fiddle. Looks great, but it is still not working in my case.

Comment: we can't help you if the code provided works and we are unable to reproduce the problem

Comment: @andrewgi yes, I understand. I have no idea why it is not working...

Comment: @andrewgi actually i discovere why. Because the button is a bootstrap button. Do you know how to override the BS style with jquery?

Comment: @RobertRoss What version of bootstrap? I'm using 3.3.7 and it still works

Comment: @mhodges 4.0.0 alpha

Comment: @RobertRoss Ahh, interesting. It breaks with 4.0+. 3.3.7 bootstrap works fine. I will try to dig into this

Comment: @RobertRoss I think I figured it out! Check if my solution works for you

Comment: @RobertRoss You're welcome! I actually just updated it again to handle successive clicks before the animation has finished. The original version did not handle this very well. You likely will want to implement something to handle this, especially with a 5 second duration on the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that the `.btn` class has a transition set by bootstrap, so in a completely random attempt to debug this, I tried setting `transition: none` thinking that maybe the transition was interfering with the jQueryUI calculations, and everything worked. You probably don't want to disable the bootstrap transitions all the time, but what you can do is add a class (that sets `transition: none;`) right before the highlight effect, and then remove that class after the `.effect()` has completed. The code would look like the following:

```js
var $transition = null;
$(".abth").click(function(e){
  var btnid='#'.concat($(this).text());
  console.log(btnid);
  var $btn = $(btnid);
  var divPosition = $btn.offset();
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: divPosition.top}, "slow");//this is working
  if ($transition !== null) {
    // if button is pressed before previous animation is completed, stop the animation 
    // immediately before starting another one to prevent issues
    $transition.stop(false, true);
  }
  $btn.addClass("no-transition");
  $transition = $btn.effect( "highlight", {color:"#FFFFFF"}, 5000, function () {
    $btn.removeClass("no-transition");
    $transition = null;
  });
});
```

```css
.no-transition {
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<li class="page-item abth"><a class="page-link" href="#">A</a></li>
<button type="button" id="A" class="btn btn-secondary alphabutton">A</button>
```